# How to make express serve static files from another upper directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, static-files

If I have an nodejs express application with folowing folder structure:

`-src
  - client
    - public
      - css
      - js
      - ...
    - views
 - server
  - server.js`

- How can I serve the static files in the public folder from the server.js file, since it is located `above` the index.js root location?
- How should the:

`app.use(express.static();`

look like?

----UPDATE---

SOLVED this by using:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../client/public')));

Comment: `path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/public/')` might also work . e.g. with `res.sendFile` instead of `express.static` .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually solved my problem by using:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../client/public')));`

Answer (score 1):

just do this, (as per your directory structure)

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/client/public'))); 
// http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

or

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/client/public')))
// http://localhost:3000/static/hello.html
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work because `__dirname` refers to the directory `server`. The problem is that public is located above server and I can't just do `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public')));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use path.join()

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

Comment: why add duplicate answer?

Comment: The one he provided was incorrect and he editted it afterward

Comment: here the first edit `app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`

Comment: I simply had a different opinion than yours initially and in terms of the answer , and I posted it , so perhaps others can decide. Have a good day !

Comment: you just add same answer

Comment: I think this doesn't work because `__dirname` refers to the directory `server`. The problem is that public is located above server and I can't just do `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public')));`

Comment: give this a try app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../src/client/public')));

Comment: @AmirHosseinRd thanks for your reply but it does not work. Why should it work ? __dirname has the path of my local machine to the /server folder so I can't start from the src folder :/