# How to display an array of items using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, middleware

I'm working on a sample webpage to show books from an array using NodeJS, but when I run the code nothing happens, there is just a blank page. I'd like to have a page with the books in the array. The code I'd written so far is below, I'd be glad if you could help!

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let books = [
    'book1',
    'book2'
];

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
app.get('/books', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Books'});
});

app.post('/books', function(req, res) {
    const id = req.body.id;
    res.redirect('/books' + id)
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Problem is that nothing happens when I run the code. Desired result would be an page with the books in the array.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "nothing happens"?

Comment: I receive neither errors nor any results, it just runs.

Comment: So what happens in the browser? Do you get a time out error? Have you checked the Network tab in the browser?

Comment: `res.render('index', {title: 'Books'})` — What is handling this? What is `index`? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: No, I receive nothing, there is only a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a webpage to be served you need to define a path to your html page like:

```
app.use('/', express.static('public'))
```

Better explained here [How to make express serve static files from another upper directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008552/how-to-make-express-serve-static-files-from-another-upper-directory)

In order to make use of app.get you want to do a GET call to your localhost:3000/books

Same with app.post but do a POST request.

Comment: The question says "to show books from an array" — so very much a *dynamic* page, not a static one.

Comment: Yes that's true I'm sorry I missed user already input __dirname